# What does the ,_,_ mean in faces,_,_ = detector.run(image = imgR, upsample_num_times = 0, adjust_threshold = 0.0)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does `,_,_` have any specific meaning in this?

`faces,_,_ = detector.run(image = imgR, upsample_num_times = 0, adjust_threshold = 0.0)`

Is it possible to code it like this?

`faces = detector.run(image = imgR, upsample_num_times = 0, adjust_threshold = 0.0)`

Comment: Tl;dr it's a way to ignore a variable. Further reading: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/role-underscore-python

Comment: I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code returns a tuple, like this:

```
spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs = generate_cards(52)
```

If you don't want all the variables offered by the tuple, it is conventional to replace one or more of them with an underscore, which is a valid variable name in Python.

```
_, hearts, _, _ = generate_cards(52)
```

The above makes it obvious what you want to do with the results of the function.  However, since that function always returns a 4-tuple, code like this:

```
hearts = generate_cards(52)
```

would actually store the entire 4-tuple in the `hearts` variable, which is not what you want.  Also, code like this

```
hearts, spades = generate_cards(52)
```

is invalid, because you're unpacking a 4-tuple into a 2-tuple, which Python does not allow.

Answer (score 1):

detector.run might be returning three values. So you need three placeholders to read them. Since code might not be using the other two return values, them have been read into `_` which is a style followed by people.